# ShowSearch function rebuilds the whole widget tree on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem when i navigate to multiple pages and then show search.
More specifically, i have a product page with some details. At the bottom there is a list of similar products.
The flow is:

1. open many similar products (so I navigate to the same screen using Navigator pushNamed).
2. then, navigate from the las product page to the search page
3. tap on search bar, open search delegate using the [showSearch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html) function

My issue is that when i tap on the search bar, then the whole widget tree is rebuilded and my app is very heavy because rebuilds the previous product pages and everything else.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to the general rebuild on keyboard changes(i.e: showing and hiding Keyboard).

I recommend to have a heavy operation like loading data from backend should be held on `initState` in `State` with `StatefullWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug and understand why do you rebuild the tree. It seems to me, that you need to simplify a navigation flow.